# Can I use a script to copy and rename a sheet in Google Sheets with the current data as the tab name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data sheet that will update weekly. I would like a script to copy the sheet and rename it with the current date. The goal is to preserve the data in the sheet weekly before it updates so that I have a record of the data.
This is the script that I have so far:

```
    /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */function myFunction() {
    let sh, temp_one_values;
    sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    temp_one_values = transpose_(sh.getSheetByName('Complete Tutoring Roster').getRange('A1:Z1000').getValues());
        {temp_one.copyTo(sh).setName(szToday);
 
    }
}

function transpose_(array) {
    return Object.keys(array[0]).map(function (col) {
        return array.map(function (row) {
            return row[col];
        });
    });
}

function CopyDataSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('11/19/2020');
};
```

I used record a macro to get the script.

I know that I need to edit the `setName` code. But I am not sure how to code it to pull the current date.

Comment: is this being deployed as an add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You just need to get the date of today in the desired format: `MM/dd/yyyy`:

  ```
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  ```
- And then use the [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) method to duplicate the sheet into the existing spreadsheet and then name it with the date of today:

  ```
  sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(today);
  ```
- You don't need to activate ranges or sheet. That is a logic generated by macros but it makes your code confusing and inefficient. Instead of getting the active sheet, use `getSheetByName` to get the desired sheet based on its name.

### Solution:

In this solution, change `Sheet1` to the name of the sheet you want to duplicate.

```
function CopyDataSheet() {
 const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
 sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet).setName(today);
};
```